# Rgd: Getting Array Key PHP

Tags: php

I have this meal_input_array

```
   [Chicken Breast] => 11
    [Marinated Dory] => 1
    [Beef] => 3

foreach($meal_input_array as $meal_input_key => $meal_input_quantity)
{

$meal_data = $mean_input_key . "**" . $meal_input_quantity;
echo $meal_data;
}
```

When I echo the result, i couldn't get the key,

```
**11**1**3**0
```

The array key name is not assign to $meal_data, may I check whats wrong with my code.

**Thanks!**

Comment: you have a typo, `$mean_input_key` should be `$meal_input_key`

Answer (score 1):

it works

```
<?php
$meal_input_array=array('Chicken Breast' => 11, 'Marinated Dory' => 1,'Beef' => 3);
//print_r($meal_input_array);
 foreach($meal_input_array as $meal_input_key => $meal_input_quantity)
 {
 //echo $meal_input_key;
 $meal_data = $meal_input_key. "  **  " .$meal_input_quantity;
 echo $meal_data;
}
```